# Bamboo configuration as code for .NET project

Tags: bamboo

Configuration as code looks like it's purely for Maven type projects.

Would it be unwise to use this for a .NET project? We're doing micro-services built in .net/C# and want to take advantage of the re usability and not have to live in a clone-driven process.

Answer (score 4):

this is a pretty new feature, and tbh I haven't looked at it yet - but, as I understand it from their documentation, they are providing tools for you to author and publish build plans or deployment projects that are Java and Maven based, but the project you are building in that plan could be any technology.

So if you were building a .NET app with MSBUILD, you would write java code to define a build plan that uses at some point an MSBUILD task:

https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs/latest/com/atlassian/bamboo/specs/builders/task/MsBuildTask.html

And you would publish that plan from the java code using their maven goal

```
mvn -Ppublish-specs
```

But once it is in Bamboo and runs, the system its building is your .NET service.

Again I have not tried this yet, but that is my understanding.